# Get all appointments for the month (including recurring appointments that are scheduled in previous months)

Tags: c#, outlook, office-automation

I am having some issues getting all the appointments from specific month. Problem is with appointments that has been scheduled with recurring setting. Is there some way to get all appointments present in outlook calendar recurring and not recurring?

The best so far I was able to achieve is to check for is `appointment.IsRecurring` and if true I can get some parameters from `recurrencePattern`. However it seems to work only for appointments that has been set in this specific month with recurring parameter. If appointment with recurrence has been set earlier, then current code does not seem to work.

Is there some way to get just all the appointments from specific month?

```
private void GetAllItems(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
  Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
  Outlook.NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
  Outlook.Items calendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;

  string restriction = $"[Start] >= '{startDate.ToShortDateString()}' AND [Start] <= '{endDate.ToShortDateString()}'";
  Outlook.Items filteredItems = calendarItems.Restrict(restriction);

  foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment in filteredItems)
  {
    DataModel dataModel = new DataModel
    {
      Subject = appointment.Subject,
    };
    this.Data.Add(dataModel);

    if (appointment.IsRecurring)
    {
      Outlook.RecurrencePattern recurrencePattern = appointment.GetRecurrencePattern();

      DataModel recurringDataModel = new DataModel
      {
        Subject = appointment.Subject,
      };
      this.Data.Add(recurringDataModel);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there - you need to set the `Items.IncludeRecurrences` property to true and call `Items.Sort` on the `Start` property to tell `Items.Restrict` to expand the recurrences. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences for more details and an example

```
  Outlook.Items calendarItems = calendarFolder.Items;
  calendarItems.Sort("[Start]");
  calendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
  string restriction = $"[Start] >= '{startDate.ToShortDateString()}' AND [Start] <= '{endDate.ToShortDateString()}'";
  Outlook.Items filteredItems = calendarItems.Restrict(restriction);
```

Comment: I actually got it working for the time being with some workaround using DayOfWeekMask, PatternStartDate, PatternEndDate, Occurrences of recurrencePattern and some calculations to simulate the pattern, but I had this strange feeling there are might be an easier way of doing this. Thank you once again for your answer! I will use this approach as it is much more shorter than mine.

Comment: Yep. Otherwise you'd also have to deal with exceptions etc. Outlook exposes a couple MAPI properties (ClipStart / ClipEnd) that give you the date of the first and last occurrences, but it would still be your responsibility to check if any occurrences actually fall into the specified range. `IncludeRecurrences/Restrict` do that for you